# how to calculate the quotient group of $U/DU$ where $U$ is an arbitrary unitary matrices, and $DU$ is diagonal unitary matrices?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, lie-groups

Question is the calculation of $U/DU$ where $U$ is a unitary matrices with non-degenerate eigenvalues, and $DU$ are diagonal unitary matrices with non-degenerate eigenvalues.

The answer is $UA_{0}U^{-1}\cong U/DU$ where $A_0$ is diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of $1,\ 1/2,\ 1/3\ ...\ 1/n$.

How ever I can see how one can calculate this the quetient is defined as follows: $G/H$ is a group its elements are the equivalence clases $[g]$
where the equivalence is defined by $g\sim g '$ if $g'=gh$. I cant find the above expression by using this definition. The original source that I encountered this problem is this; [image: picutre.]

Comment: You miss something completely. The original source said that $\mathfrak{M}$ can be represented as a homogeneous space $\mathscr{U}/D\mathscr{U}$. To do so, we need to show that the group action of $\mathscr{U}$ on $\mathfrak{M}$ is transitive and the isotropy group $\mathscr{U}_{A_0}$ is nothing but $D\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: @ChoF           I don't understand, can you elaborate more. What we need to show exactly?

Comment: The question is incomprehensible. Is $U$ supposed to be a group or a matrix?

Comment: @physshyp I suggest you at least read the Wikipedia page "Homogeneous space". It's not simple.

Answer (score 3):

**[Reference]** [Wikipedia: Homogeneous space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space) and [Wikipedia: Group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action)

*Note. I will use a general notation for the unitary groups.*

Let $U(n)$ be the set of unitary matrices, and let $DU(n)$ be the set of unitary diagonal matrices.

> *Note.* $DU(n)$ is a closed subgroup of the Lie group $U(n)$ so that the quotient group $U(n)/DU(n)$ is a smooth manifold.

Let $\mathfrak{M}\equiv\{ UA_0U^{-1} : U\in U(n) \}$ where $A_0$ is the diagonal matrix with entries $1,\frac{1}{2},\dotsc,\frac{1}{n}$.
Notice that $\mathfrak{M}$ is *not* a group, since $\mathfrak{M}$ does not contain the identity matrix $I$.

The unitary group $U(n)$ acts on $\mathfrak{M}$ (by conjugation)
$$
U(n) \times \mathfrak{M} \to \mathfrak{M} \quad\text{defined by}\quad
(V, UA_0U^{-1}) \mapsto V(UA_0U^{-1})V^{-1} 
$$
for $V\in U(n)$ and $UA_0U^{-1}\in\mathfrak{M}$. In general the action of $V$ on $UA_0U^{-1}$ is denoted by $V\cdot(UA_0U^{-1})$.

(1) The action is **well-defined** since
$$
V\cdot(UA_0U^{-1}) \equiv V(UA_0U^{-1})V^{-1} = (VU)A_0(VU)^{-1} \in \mathfrak{M}
$$
(2) (**Identity**) For the identity matrix $I$, we have
$$
I\cdot(UA_0U^{-1}) \equiv I(UA_0U^{-1})I^{-1} = UA_0U^{-1}
$$
(3) (**Compatibility**) For $V,W\in U(n)$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
(VW)\cdot(UA_0U^{-1}) &\equiv (VW)(UA_0U^{-1})(VW)^{-1} \\
&= V(W(UA_0U^{-1})W^{-1})V^{-1} = V\cdot(W\cdot(UA_0U^{-1}))
\end{align*}
$$
(4) Moreover the action is **differentiable** because it consists of matrix multiplications.

> **Claim.** The homogeneous space $\mathfrak{M}$ is diffeomorphic to the quotient group $U(n)/DU(n)$.

1. **$\mathfrak{M}$ is a homogeneous space.**

> A **homogeneous space** for a (Lie) group $G$ is a non-empty (smooth manifold) $X$ on which $G$ acts [transitively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Types_of_actions) (from [Wikipedia: Homogeneous space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space)).

In our case, the action of $U(n)$ on $\mathfrak{M}$ is faithful so that "$\mathfrak{M}$ is a homogeneous space for $U(n)$" is equivalent to "$\mathfrak{M}$ is a single $U(n)$-orbit". But this is trivial by the definition of
$$
\mathfrak{M}=\{ U\cdot A_0\equiv UA_0U^{-1} : U\in U(n) \} = \text{$U(n)\cdot A_0$ (the $U(n)$-orbit of $A_0$) }
$$

2. **$\mathfrak{M}\cong U(n)/DU(n)$**

> For a fixed $x\in X$, consider the map from $G$ to $X$ given by $g\mapsto g\cdot x$ for all $g\in G$. The image of this map is $G\cdot x$, the $G$-orbit of $x$. The standard quotient theorem of set theory then gives a *natural bijection* between $G/G_x$ and $G\cdot x$. Here $G_x=\{g\in G : g\cdot x=x\}$ denotes the **stabilizer subgroup** of $G$ with respect to $x$ (from [Wikipedia: Group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside's_lemma)).

The statement above is very basic fact. Moreover, the *bijection* becomes a diffeomorphism when $G$ is a Lie group. In our case, since $\mathfrak{M}$ is a single $U(n)$-orbit of $A_0$, we have
$$
\mathfrak{M} \cong U(n)/U(n)_{A_0}
$$
It remains to show that the stabilizer $U(n)_{A_0}=\{V\in U(n) : V\cdot A_0=A_0\}$ is nothing but $DU(n)$. It is easy to check using matrix multiplication and leave it to an exercise.

Comment: I don't get why the $U$ acts as conjugation.

Comment: @physshyp Attached statements why $U(n)$ acts on $\mathfrak{M}$ as conjugation. I suggest to read the Wikipedia page "Group action".